# Explanatory variables in a Lin-log model

Tags: r, linear-model

I have a data set and I want to fit a `Lin-log` model. Is it possible to apply the log transformation only to some of the explanatory variables or should the log transformation be applied to all of the explanatory variables?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the context/data. For one thing, if an explanatory variable can take negative values, then applying the log-transformation is not really appropriate. Putting the negativity of explanatory variables aside (i.e. let's assume that they must be positive), a log-transformation can be always be applied as an exercise in mathematics - but the real question is whether the result is a better fit. The way you phrased your question seems to imply that if you apply log-transformation for one variable, then you must apply it for all the other variables - there is no reason to suppose this at all - have a look at your fits, and see which ones come out better. Furthermore, you may know in advance that the explanatory variable is better suited to having a log-transformation applied due to physical reasoning.

As an aside - have a look at Box-Cox transformations - this may help you decide whether what transformation to use on each variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this apply for interactive terms too? Lets say i want to interact log of Net official development assistance received (ODA) with governance. Governance is estimated as a score from -2.5 to 2.5. So i cannot apply to to governance but can i interact log of Net ODA with governance. My hypothesis is that ODA will positively affect FDI in cases of good governance. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this apply for interactive terms too? Lets say i want to interact log of Net official development assistance received (ODA) with governance. Governance is estimated as a score from -2.5 to 2.5. So i cannot apply log to governance but can i interact log of Net ODA with governance. My hypothesis is that ODA will positively affect FDI in cases of good governance. Thank you

Comment: Forgive my ignorance - i do not know what the ODA and Governance variables mean. However, if your interaction term is always positive, then by all means perform a log-transformation on it. If it isn't it is certainly possible to force it to be positive by adding some constant to the interaction term before logging it. Basically, you are allowed to apply whatever transformation you like to whatever variables, as long as it's mathematically valid. The question pretty much always boils down to whether the model is reasonable and gives a reasonable fit.